# jshint gives "missing semicolon" or not based on whether the function is void?

Tags: javascript, jshint

I am using jshint in VSCode. jshint gives a "missing semicolon" warning at the end '}' of the function below

```
void function doSomething(){
    console.log('Hello, World');
}
```

[image]

And adding the semicolon satisfies jshint:

[image]

But after I remove `void`, the warning goes away without the semicolon:

```
void function doSomething(){
    console.log('Hello, World');
}
```

[image]

What is the logic behind this? More generally, is there official style guidance such as [PEP8 in Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for Javascript addressing the best practice for semicolon?

Comment: The posted code contains a syntax error. And even if I add the missing `()`, I cannot reproduce the problem. Add the actual code and the full linting error message you get.

Comment: @str, thanks and apologies. I got the issue backwards in the original post, it is when the `void` keyword is added that jshint gives that warning.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void

Comment: @str, now I understand why you post this link:)

Answer (score 2):

With the linting rules you have:

- Function declarations do not need to be followed by a semi-colon.
- Expressions, including those which include a function expression, do.

By putting the `void` operator before the `function` keyword, you force it into expression context.

Since it is in expression context, you do nothing with the function in the expression, and you void the result, it becomes pointless. The expression doesn't do anything at all. It doesn't even create a variable with the function stored in it, which is why this errors:

```js
void function x() { console.log(1) };
x();
```

> More generally, what's the best practice rule on semicolns in javascript?

A *highly* opinionated subject.

Comment: `void` here doesn't mean "it is a function that doesn't return anything"?

Comment: @JaneJ — No, it doesn't. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void

Comment: thanks, I just assumed it meant the same as in c++... btw, I also changed the second part of my question to something less opinionated.